Azure Global Administrator - "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation"
I am a global administrator for my company's Azure account. I understood this to mean I have full permission to access resource, manage users etc.
When trying to make some IAM changes however I'm unable to see a list of users to assign roles to, not even my own account. (F12 tools show the request to enumerate users is 403). Going to the Entra ID module in Azure portal and it turns out I can't see or do anything in there, i receive "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation." or "Unable to complete due to service connection error. Please try again later." errors.
It seems my account is bugged or is there something with Azure roles that I'm missing?
We don't have a support package so can't access Azure support

For any operations on the Azure there are 2 additional restrictions that would cause such issues:

The permissions on the resource itself is not assigned to the user principal which is trying to access it.
The network configuration does not allow the access to the resource because it might be set up with specific IP's and the IP from which the user is trying might not be whitelisted there.


Although you are a Microsoft Entra ID Global Admin, you need to explicitly add the resource role when managing Azure resources. You can do the following steps and retry:
Microsoft Entra Id -> Properties -> Access Management For Azure Resource turn to Yes
After above, your account will get the Role User Access Administrator, with this role, you can obtain a high enough azure resource permission
